# PyQt5 dial component as "rotary encoder"

Tags: python, pyqt5, encoder

I need help with a new component in PyQt5 like dial component but without dead zone from 5 to 6 o'clock and which can be rotated endlessly like common hardware rotary encoder.

Comment: I'm not a Qt user, but a quick search of the docs shows that the QDial widget behaves like you ask if the `wrapping` property is set to True.

Comment: Holly cow! Seems that you're right! I'm not a familiar Qt user too but I wasn't able to find it. Plase advice what keywards did you use - I've tried a lot of variants with no result.